# jQuery datepicker to handle Fiscal Calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to create jQuery Datepicker to handle Fiscal Calendar?

[image]

Searched all over the internet, couldn't find any way to do this.

What I need is to set custom start and end date.

Thanks

**Edit**

What I want is to define my own `custom Month`. For example: Instead of having `October 2016`, I can have `Period 1` and the dates for it should be instead of `Oct 1 - Oct 31`, it should be `Sep 25 - Oct 29`. Then `Period 2` - from `Oct 30 - Nov 26`.

There is no specific pattern for this, but I do have a list of dates for each Period I want to construct.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for if i am not wrong

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Datepicker
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    numberOfMonths: [4, 2],
    defaultDate: '01 / 01 / ' + new Date().getFullYear(),
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<input name="my-date" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Please take a look at new Edit.